# Interlocked.CompareExchange doesn't provide correct memory ordering

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, memory-barriers, lock-free

I'm trying to implement lock-free concurrent pool of objects in C#. To implement *happens before* behavior, I'm using *CompareExchange* which acts as a full memory fence (at least on x86 and ARM). Here is my code:

```cs
private sealed class Command
{
  internal Command Next;
  internal string Data;
}

private static volatile Command pool;

private static Command RentCommand()
{
  Command current, next = pool;
  do
  {
    if (next is null)
    {
      current = new();
      break;
    }

    current = next;
  }
  while (!ReferenceEquals(next = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref pool, current.Next, current), current));

  string data = current.Data;

  // catch unexpected behavior with debugger
  if (data is not null)
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

  current.Next = null;
  return current;
}

private static void ReturnCommand(Command cmd)
{
  cmd.Data = null;
  Command currentValue = cmd.Next = pool;
  Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref pool, cmd, currentValue);
}
```

There are two methods: *RentCommand* and *ReturnCommand*. The first one requests a new *Command* from the pool, the second one returns it back. I'm expecting that `cmd.Data = null` happens before `cmd` returned back to the pool inside of *ReturnCommand*. As a result, inside of *RentCommand* the thread should see that *Data* field is always **null**. But the debugger stops at breakpoint which is coded explicitly inside of *RentCommand*. CompareExchange is used on both sides: consumer and producer. So they can run concurrently (both methods can be called safely by different threads) in theory. Here is the code for test that reproduces this situation:

```cs
public static async Task Test()
        {
            static void RunTask(string taskName)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 40_000; i++)
                {
                    var cmd1 = RentCommand();
                    cmd1.Data = taskName + "_1";
                    Thread.Yield();
                    var cmd2 = RentCommand();
                    cmd2.Data = taskName + "_2";
                    cmd2.Data.GetHashCode();
                    ReturnCommand(cmd1);
                    ReturnCommand(cmd2);
                }
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task1")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task2")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task3")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task4")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task5")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task6")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task7")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task8")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task9")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task10")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task11")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task12")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task13")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task14")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task15")),
                Task.Run(static () => RunTask("Task16")));
        }
```

It seems like CPU or JIT reorders `cmd.Data = null` and put after CompareExchange. However, I tried to test this hypothesis and put `Interlocked.MemoryBarrier()` explicitly after assignment but before CompareExchange. No luck.

The test works as expected if I put `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` on both methods. But I don't understand why? Monitor lock inserts read barrier at its beginning and write barrier in the end (regardless of other activities under the hood such as pausing thread while waiting for lock).

Comment: I don't know C#, but could it have a circular reference, `current.Next == current`, so that multiple threads obtain the same instance?

Comment: You may want `lock-free` instead of `compare-and-swap`. The latter is a technique you are using, but what you are looking for is someone who understands the gotchas of lock free operations

Comment: Why does `ReturnCommand` not retry the CAS on failure?  It just drops the `cmd` if it raced with another thread trying to return an entry to the `pool` linked list?  But yes, if it does succeed, any node visible to other threads should have `cmd.Data = null;`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, to avoid spin loops. It's fine to drop `cmd` if it cannot be returned back to the pool.

Comment: So your real use-case doesn't care about losing them either?  Are they really so expensive to allocate that it's worth bothering with a pool at all, instead of just always allocating a new one and letting C#'s garbage collector sort it out?

Comment: @PeterCordes, because it's better to allocate sometimes rather than allocate always

Comment: Ok, if you benchmarked it and it was a speedup, then sure, interesting.  You could equally say it's better to contend never than sometimes, and not have to run any atomic RMW instructions for most allocations or deallocations.  (Which are full memory barriers on x86, and hurt memory-level parallelism significantly since they have to wait for all earlier stores to commit to L1d cache before any later loads can read from cache.)  Assuming the runtime uses per-thread memory pools for efficient allocation, a typical allocation can be local, not needing to interact with other threads.

Answer (score 2):

I found a root cause. Let's imagine that we have 3 competing threads, and two objects inside of the pool: B -> A (B references A). All three threads executing *RentCommand*:

1. T1 rents B (passes through CompareExchange), T2 rents A (passes through CompareExchange), T3 sees `current=B, next=A` but didn't pass CompareExchange yet
2. T1 returns B, T3 executes CompareExchange. This operation is successful because its `current` is equal to `pool`. However, its `next` points to A. CompareExchange swaps B to A successfully. However, T2 didn't return A yet. As a result, A becomes available for rent while in use.

Seems like it's typical [ABA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) problem when trying to use lock-free algorithm.

**Conclusion**: thread-safe object pooling using singly linked-list cannot be implemented correctly.

Comment: There are lock-free stack data structures, but yeah doing it with a linked list might require tagging pointers to "claim" them or something, to avoid problems like this.  As discussed in comments on [Is this lock-free dlist insertion is safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/134596329) even one direction of a linked list for insert only is non-trivial, and known-good algorithms use an extra bit in the pointer of a node.

Comment: For a pool, you might have less contention with a queue instead of stack, and that's easy to implement with an array.  Or maybe a linked list in a language like C# where garbage collection solves the deallocation problem for lock-free algorithms; insert at the other end you remove from, maybe.

Comment: @PeterCordes, array is not an option, it has limited size. Resizing array requires exclusive lock.

Comment: How big do you want to let a free-list get before you start dropping objects to let them get garbage-collected?  Whatever that size is, you could make your array that size.  An unbounded size for the pool doesn't seem necessary or a good idea.

Comment: Generally you would not expose the list node externally, so each time you return an object to the pool a new list wrapper is allocated. Then it has a new reference identity and won't be an ABA problem.